# Three.js - TypeError: THREE.XLoader is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I decided to see if I could import a [DirectX Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.x) and found this [XLoader](https://github.com/adrs2002/threeXfileLoader). However I can't seem to initialize it at all. Now, I am the kind of guy who likes to link directly to the library so that whenever there is an update I don't have to re-download and re-upload. My test code looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>


<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/loaders/XLoader.js"></script>
<script>

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.001, 10000 );

var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
var Texloader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

var loader = new THREE.XLoader(manager, Texloader);
loader.load(['FrigateHull.x'], function (object) {
        console.log(object);
},function (xhr) {
        if (xhr.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
            console.log(Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded');
        }},
function (xhr) {
    console.log(xhr);
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The error I am getting from this setup is this:

```
TypeError: THREE.XLoader is not a constructor
```

I have also tried the `import` method as described in the examples but still same error. I have also downloaded the git to the server and tried linking to that, but it said something about `global is undefined`.

What am I missing, or is there another DirectX Model Loader out there I could try?

Answer (score 1):

Should be like this:

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script type="module">
      import { XLoader } from "https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/loaders/XLoader.js";
      // ....
      var loader = new XLoader(manager, Texloader);
      // ....
</script>
```

Although the `TypeError: THREE.XLoader is not a constructor` exception is resolved, there are still other problems.

Let's look at the source code of `XLoader.js`:

```js
import {
    AnimationClip,
    AnimationMixer,
    Bone,
    BufferGeometry,
    FileLoader,
    Float32BufferAttribute,
    FrontSide,
    Loader,
    LoaderUtils,
    Matrix4,
    Mesh,
    MeshPhongMaterial,
    Quaternion,
    Skeleton,
    SkinnedMesh,
    TextureLoader,
    Uint16BufferAttribute,
    Vector2,
    Vector3
} from "../../../build/three.module.js";

// ...
```

We don't have `../../../build/three.module.js` code.

It is recommended that you clone the repository of [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js), and then `npm install` → `npm start` to start the project, instead of viewing it directly in the browser, which involves a lot of `import` and `export` of modules depends on front-end construction tools.

Comment: And how would I go about `npm`ing to a remote server which I do not have `ssh` access to?

Comment: As long as you can connect to the Internet, install `Git` and `Node.js` on your computer, clone the repository, and execute `npm` related commands in the project `package.json` directory.

Comment: So you are saying if I install `Node.js` on my local computer and do the commands needed, it will FTP all necessary files (changes) to my remote hosting service?

Comment: project, Front-End project are mostly used `NPM (package.json)`, Like a Java project `Maven(pom.xml)`, need to build and package.

Comment: not this way: 
`<script src="foo.js"> </script>`, 
`<script src="bar.js"> </script>`, 
`<script src="qux.js"> </script>`, 
`...`